# How to BuildMyOwnKernel, bumping +1 for revision number version?

Tags: kernel, ppa, gnupg

I'm facing a hard time with Linux 3.13 from Trusty but, it is another topic (http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-server@lists.ubuntu.com/msg06775.html), so, I decided to backport the Linux 3.16 from Utopic.

Also, I'll need to sign my Linux version with my GPG key and upload it to my PPA later but, first, I am unable to bump +1 to Linux `revision` version... Can someone help me with that?!

Here is the procedure to manually backport it (which works, as-is, without bumping +1 to `revision` version):

Instructions from: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

1- Add Utopic's deb-src to Trusty's sources.list:

```
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted universe multiverse
```

2- Run the following commands:

```
mkdir ~/linux/source -p
cd ~/linux/source
sudo apt-get install fakeroot
sudo apt-get build-dep linux
apt-get source linux
cd linux-3.16.0/
debuild -uc -us
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.16.0-4_3.16.0-4.9_all.deb linux-headers-3.16.0-4-generic_3.16.0-4.9_amd64.deb linux-image-3.16.0-4-generic_3.16.0-4.9_amd64.deb linux-image-extra-3.16.0-4-generic_3.16.0-4.9_amd64.deb
```

3- Done! Linux 3.16 from Utopic, compiled and installed into Trusty! First phase okay...

But now, I need to bump its `revision` version to, something like this: "3.16.0-5.0". To sign it with my GPG and upload it to my PPA.

Then, to achieve this, before compiling and packaging it, I edited the "debian changelog" file:

```
cd linux-3.16.0/
vi debian.master/changelog
```

...to add:

```
linux (3.16.0-5.0) trusty; urgency=low

  [ Thiago Martins ]

  * Backporting it to Trusty

 -- Thiago Martins <thiagocmartinsc@gmail.com.br>  Sat, 19 Jul 2014 20:42:13 -0300
```

Now, the command `debuild` fails to package it, the following error appear at near the end of the process:

```
debuild
...
Use of uninitialized value $filename in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Lib.pm line 410.
dh_systemd_start
Can't stat debian/linux-tools-3.16.0-5: No such file or directory
 at /usr/bin/dh_systemd_start line 127.
Can't stat debian/linux-cloud-tools-3.16.0-5: No such file or directory
 at /usr/bin/dh_systemd_start line 127.
Can't stat debian/linux-image-3.16.0-5-generic: No such file or directory
 at /usr/bin/dh_systemd_start line 127.
Can't stat debian/linux-image-extra-3.16.0-5-generic: No such file or directory
...
...
Can't stat debian/vlan-modules-3.16.0-5-generic-di: No such file or directory
 at /usr/bin/dh_systemd_start line 127.
Can't stat debian/ipmi-modules-3.16.0-5-generic-di: No such file or directory
 at /usr/bin/dh_systemd_start line 127.
Debug: install-indep
Debug: binary-indep
dh_installchangelogs -i
dh_installdocs -i
dh_compress -i
dh_fixperms -i
dh_installdeb -i
flock -w 60 /home/tmartins/linux/source/linux-3.16.0/debian/.LOCK dh_gencontrol -i
dh_md5sums -i
dh_builddeb -i
dpkg-deb: building package `linux-source-3.16.0' in `../linux-source-3.16.0_3.16.0-5.0_all.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package `linux-doc' in `../linux-doc_3.16.0-5.0_all.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package `linux-headers-3.16.0-5' in `../linux-headers-3.16.0-5_3.16.0-5.0_all.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package `linux-tools-common' in `../linux-tools-common_3.16.0-5.0_all.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package `linux-cloud-tools-common' in `../linux-cloud-tools-common_3.16.0-5.0_all.deb'.
Debug: install-perarch
# Add the tools.
...
...
dpkg-deb: building package `linux-tools-3.16.0-5' in `../linux-tools-3.16.0-5_3.16.0-5.0_amd64.deb'.
dh_strip -plinux-cloud-tools-3.16.0-5
dh_installchangelogs -plinux-cloud-tools-3.16.0-5
dh_installdocs -plinux-cloud-tools-3.16.0-5
dh_compress -plinux-cloud-tools-3.16.0-5
dh_fixperms -plinux-cloud-tools-3.16.0-5
dh_shlibdeps -plinux-cloud-tools-3.16.0-5
dh_installdeb -plinux-cloud-tools-3.16.0-5
flock -w 60 /home/tmartins/linux/source/linux-3.16.0/debian/.LOCK dh_gencontrol -plinux-cloud-tools-3.16.0-5
dh_md5sums -plinux-cloud-tools-3.16.0-5
dh_builddeb -plinux-cloud-tools-3.16.0-5
dpkg-deb: building package `linux-cloud-tools-3.16.0-5' in `../linux-cloud-tools-3.16.0-5_3.16.0-5.0_amd64.deb'.
Debug: module-check-generic
install -d /home/tmartins/linux/source/linux-3.16.0/debian.master/abi/3.16.0-5.0/amd64
find /home/tmartins/linux/source/linux-3.16.0/debian/build/build-generic/ -name \*.ko | \
                sed -e 's/.*\/\([^\/]*\)\.ko/\1/' | sort > /home/tmartins/linux/source/linux-3.16.0/debian.master/abi/3.16.0-5.0/amd64/generic.modules
II: Checking modules for generic...previous or current modules file missing!
   /home/tmartins/linux/source/linux-3.16.0/debian.master/abi/3.16.0-5.0/amd64/generic.modules
   /home/tmartins/linux/source/linux-3.16.0/debian.master/abi/3.16.0-4.9/amd64/generic.modules
make: *** [module-check-generic] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

What more should I need to change, to bump +1 for my Linux release version (from 4.9 to 5.0)? So, `debuild` process will finish okay... I think that there is something to do with `abi` but, I'm not a Ubuntu Linux Kernel maintainer (or a coder), so, I don't know how to proceed from here...

I really appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am guessing by looking at those errors, half the problem is that directories the source are in will probably be called  something like  `*3.16.0-4`, not `*3.16.0-5` as it expects from your changes to what version it is. The other issue it likely is that `*3.16.0-5` will need dependencies to match that version, which probably don't exist/aren't compatible... N.B. using the existing packages for Utopic *might* work - I had vaguely similar success installing a Fedora 20 kernel in Fedora 19 (not Ubuntu though)

Comment: Do you absolutely have to do a +1? You could instead append `~1` (`~` is considered less than everything), and so have the version string be `3.16.0-4.9~1`. You could also look at the `backportpackage` tool in the `ubuntu-dev-tools` package, which automates the process of backporting a package, adjusting the version number so that the new package is between Trusty and Utopic, and uploading it to a PPA (if you want to). The syntax to save the source package locally would be `backportpackage -s utopic -d trusty -w . --dont-sign linux`.

Comment: Good point!! I'm trying it with 4.9.1 now... I'll take a look into ubuntu-dev-tools.... Tks!     ^_^

Comment: Bumping it to "4.9.1" didn't worked either, trying "4.9~1" now... Next, I'll try "backportpackage -b -s utopic -d trusty -w . linux"...

Comment: Bumping it to "4.9~1" didn't worked either...    :-(

Answer (score 2):

The build fails at module checking, which I think is because `/home/tmartins/linux/source/linux-3.16.0/debian.master/abi/3.16.0-4.9` does not exist. You can skip the checking by using the `skipmodule=true` parameter. When I build with `fakeroot debian/rules`, I will do this:

```
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic skipmodule=true
```

This parameter should also apply to `debuild`.

But in later stage, the build may fail again at ABI check, so you will have to use `skipabi=true` as well, so the full command will become:

```
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic skipmodule=true skipabi=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error when trying to build my own Ubuntu kernel.

I had updated debian.master/changelog to:

```
linux (3.13.0-107.154+studog-01) trusty; urgency=low
```

The build failed (paraphrased, I lost the original output):

```
find /home/studog/linux-3.16.0/debian/build/build-generic/ -name \*.ko | \
            sed -e 's/.*\/\([^\/]*\)\.ko/\1/' | sort > /home/studog/linux-3.16.0/debian.master/abi/3.16.0-studog-0.0/amd64/generic.modules
II: Checking modules for generic...previous or current modules file missing!
```

Note the extraversion wasn't quite right in the attempted path reference, although the correct path (debian.master/abi/3.13.0-107.154+studog-01) did exist. I changed the changelog to be instead

```
linux (3.13.0-107.154+studog01) trusty; urgency=low
```

and it worked. It seems like the build system doesn't enjoy extra-versions that contain dashes.

Anthony Wong's workaround with skipmodule and skipabi worked to correct the problem as well, but I preferred changing the extra-version instead.